# É possível usar Session em Windows Service?

Tags: c#, services

Tenho uma aplicação em Windows Service, e preciso guardar o estado enquanto um determinado método é executado, qual o melhor meio de fazer isso?

Comment: Seria interessante você detalhar melhor a pergunta. Você precisa guardar o estado de que? Quando? Por que? Tem como colocar o código para entendermos?

Comment: Tenho um Timer no serviço, que executa uma determinada rotina que pode demorar além da execução do próximo Timer, ai obviamente não quero deixar executar novamente enquanto esse primeiro Timer estiver sendo executado, não quero colocar isso no banco de dados, gostaria de alguma forma que identificasse isso na própria aplicação.

Comment: @Raí, gostaria de lhe sugerir a seguinte leitura: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//428303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode armazenar em um objeto.
O "Serviço" é uma instância de sua classe, logo você pode armazenar qualquer coisa dentro dela.

```
public class MyTask
{
    public void LongOperation()
    {
        // seu código que pode demorar aqui
    }

    public Task LongOperationAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(delegate () { this.LongOperation(); });
    }
}

public class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    Timer _timer;
    MyTask _currentTask;
    bool _called;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
        _currentTask = new MyTask();
        _called = false;
        _timer = new Timer(5000);
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private async void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO:
        //      talvez você precise usar uma sincronização à nível de Thread (lock) aqui
        if (_called)
        {
            // função ja foi chamada
            return;
        }
        _called = true;
        await _currentTask.LongOperationAsync();
        _called = false;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        base.OnStop();
    }
}
```